# how to reduce the summation value of binary variable to 1 , Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I have a binary set of variable Viu whose value can be either 0 or 1 ,
There can be multiple time when(ith value of Viu) V_1_A is assigned value 1

There is another integer Variable Xi which holds some value and is assigned to i when he is assigned the value of 1.....

For eg. when V_1_A is selected  X_1=10;
My linear equation is 
V_1_A * X_1_ =10 i:e 1* 10=10

As mentioned above V_1 could get assigned to V_1_A and also V_1_B, I want that the summation of V_1 should not be 2 but should get reduced to 1 so that the value Xi be multiplied only although Vi is selected multiple times.

I am very new to ILP, please help

Comment: V_1_A*X_1=10 is not a linear equation. To fix that, it would help to know what X_1 should be when V_1_A = 0.

Comment: It's not possible to contact users via flags. They can be notified using @SagarikaKhandelwal for example. But it was not needed here, as in certain cases it's automomatic.

Comment: @prubin i need to have something like this: if sum of some variables (V[i,u,p]) is equal or more than 1 then another variable (z[i]) should be equal to 1 else it should be 0. I then want to use Z[i] to multiply with a constant value reserved for indices i Something like If sum of V[i,u,p] >=1 then Z[i]=1 else sum of V[i,u,p] =0 then Z[i]=0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll answer the question raised in one of the comments: how to get Z[i] to take the value 1 if a sum of V[i,...] variables is >= 1 and to take the value 0 if the sum of the V[i,...] is 0, assuming that V and Z are binary. You just need the following constraints:

1. Z[i] <= sum of V[i,...] (which ensures that Z[i] is 0 when the sum is zero); and
2. Z[i] >= V[i,...] for every V in the summation (which ensures that Z[i] is 1 if any V[i,...] that is part of the sum is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help @prubin
For the second constraint did you mean Z[i] >=  sum of i, sum of u, sum of p V[iup], because in that situation how can Z[i] will be 1, since the summation of these indices  be greater than 5 or 8 in case of multiple assignments of i with u and p

Comment: No, I meant that the second constraint is Z[i] >= a single V, repeated for each relevant V.

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks much @Prubin